# Repair or mount broken sd card in Ubuntu

Tags: external-sd, linux

I have this sd card from my phone which gave errors in the phone. When I put it in a cardreader in my ubuntu laptop it mounts the first 16Mb partition, but I cannot get the second to mount.
What should the filesystem be of that partition and how can I mount it or repair it

Comment: We have no way of knowing, could be corrupted or encrypted, exFat, Fat32, ext2, ext3, ext4, or??? ..  Try viewing the device in gparted.

Comment: What was that 2nd partition used for? That could give a clue. If Link2SD, it's usually some ExtFS (ext2/3/4).